# In the Lineweaver-Burk Plot, why does the x-intercept = -1/Km?

Tags: enzymes, enzyme-kinetics, kinetics

Taking the reciprocal of both sides of the Michaelis-Menten equation yields the Lineweaver-Burk Equation:

$ \dfrac{1}{V} = \dfrac{K_m}{V_{max}}\dfrac{1}{[S]}+ \dfrac{1}{V_{max}} $

Plotting a $ \dfrac{1}{V}$ vs. $\dfrac{1}{[S]}$ graph, I am told that:

y-int $= \dfrac{1}{V_{max}}$ and

x-int $= -\dfrac{1}{K_m}$

How are these relationships derived from the lineweaver-burk plot?  I can see how the y-intercept can be equal to $\dfrac{1}{V_{max}}$ if $\dfrac{1}{[S]} = 0$, but I don't see how x-int $= -\dfrac{1}{K_m}$ by setting $\dfrac{1}{V} = 0$? Can someone demonstrate how these relationships were derived?

Comment: Equation of a line: `y=mx+c` or `y=m(x-d)` where `c` is y-intercept and `d` is x-intercept. The general equation of a line is `y-y₁=m(x-x₁)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set $ \dfrac{1}{V} = 0$ and solve for $\dfrac{1}{[S]}$:

$ 0 = \dfrac{K_m}{V_{max}}\dfrac{1}{[S]}+ \dfrac{1}{V_{max}} $

$ -\dfrac{1}{V_{max}} = \dfrac{K_m}{V_{max}}\dfrac{1}{[S]}$

$ -1 = {K_m}\dfrac{1}{[S]}$

$ -\dfrac{1}{K_m} = \dfrac{1}{[S]} = $ x-intercept